# Is it possible to include a CSS file into another CSS file with a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a large CSS file, and I would like to include other CSS files for special cases using media queries.

Is it safe to use `@import` in CSS like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {    
    @import url('/css/styles-480.css');    
}
```

Comment: Generally using @import is slowing the browsers display. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912899/css-import-best-practices). A basic rule in web optimization is simply to minimize the number of requests, especially sequential requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of importing within a CSS file, I would recommend that you download the CSS file in parallel if it is required:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)"
href="/css/styles-480.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The problem with using `@import` is that the second file is only downloaded after the CSS file containing `@import` is completely downloaded and parsed. Regardless of whether you are overriding all your rules or some of your rules, this approach is faster, since it doesn't load the files sequentially.

Comment: That depends - if the stylesheet where the `@import` is contains other styles that the OP needs to load anyway, then moving this `@import` out of that stylesheet won't make a difference.

Comment: @BoltClock True, I was assuming the OP was overriding all the current rules with `@import`

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, that isn't true. My approach is faster regardless, because `@import` only kicks in once the CSS file has been completely downloaded and parsed. That means the files load sequentially.

Comment: I was referring to the bit about loading an unnecessary stylesheet - the stylesheet will *always* be loaded regardless of where you declare it, as long as it is declared. Using a link tag is indisputably faster than using `@import`, but it doesn't always save an HTTP request.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I was referring to `moving this @import out of that stylesheet won't make a difference.` It will, it'll keep the loading times the same if the file isn't required, and make them shorter if it is.

Comment: Alright. Just trying to clear things up a bit in the comments :)

Answer (score 15):

It's not valid to have an `@import` within a `@media` rule, so what you have won't work.

The correct way to do this is even simpler — `@import` itself accepts a media query after the URL:

```css
@import url('/css/styles-480.css') only screen and (max-width: 480px);
```

This syntax is [introduced in CSS2.1 for use with media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import), but [media queries will also work](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) since they're a direct extension from media types.

Remember that `@import` rules can only exist at the beginning of a stylesheet.

If you're concerned about load performance, you may want to use a separate `<link>` element in your page head to refer to this stylesheet instead of an `@import`, [as shown by Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124581/is-is-possible-to-include-css-file-into-another-css-file/14124648#14124648). However, either way will work just fine.