# Putting @import at the bottom of CSS

Tags: css, import

I have learned that it is generally not recommended to use `@import` for page performance. If I put `@import` at the bottom of my css file and use the style not for the elements at a page load but for the elements for later user  interactions, will there still be any performance cost? For example, if I use the style `@import`ed for a popup that user clicks to display, is `@import` still a poor choice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS @import Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912899/css-import-best-practices)

Comment: The link suggested does not answer my question on using @import for the styling of the elements to be used for later user interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Importing another CSS file from a pseudo-class, which is what I assume you meant by "user interactions", will still impact performance. A significantly faster way to achieve the same result is changing the property values through JavaScript event listeners.

Comment: Why is there a performance cost when there is no blocking download of css file on page load?

Comment: @narusawa Because the browser will need to request to download the css file, then parse it. Using JavaScript will negate the need to download.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `<link>`'s appropriately ordered?